# Symfony Forms, filter the Embedded Collection of Forms to be showed

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-forms

Consider a Many-to-Many relationship and a Form that is showing the relationship as a Collection.

I want to only render entities of that relation that match a given criteria.

***Example:***

Category and Products are in Many-to-Many.
When editing the Category I only want to provide Products that are currently available.

When I add another Product I need to update all Products. I have the updated list of Products with available Products only and I have a list of all Products, now I have to merge these Products and I don't know how to do this efficient.

***Dirty Solution***

I have a possible solution in mind, however it is not a nice solution.
Add two methods `getAvailableProducts()` and `setAvailableProducts()`. However, the `setAvailableProducts()` method involves a lot of computation power, since you need to compare it to the `$availableProducts`.

Isn't there a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can filter doctrine collections by using `Criteria`. This is explained in detail in [the documentation chapter **8.8. Filtering Collections**](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/working-with-associations.html#filtering-collections).

You use the class `Doctrine\Common\Collections\Criteria` to define the conditions of your filtering and then you can do like this:

```
$filteredCollection = $collection->matching($criteria);
```

Another option would be to left-join with conditions in your entity repository. In that case the collection will already be hydrated with only the members according to the conditions in your query.

### Update

You could also simply make a special method `getAvailableProductsForCategory` in your `ProductRepository` where you pass a category as a parameter to the method.

```
class ProductRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function getAvailableProductsForCategory(Category $category)
    {
        $products = $this->createQueryBuilder('p')
            ->leftJoin('p.categories', 'c')
            ->where('p.available = true')
            ->andWhere('c = :category_id')
            ->setParameters(
                array(
                    'category_id' => $category->getId(),
                )
            )
            ->getQuery()
            ->getResult();

        return $products;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I know about `Criteria`. My Issue is that I don't know how to set the updated Products, since I can't just update the Products association. I need to create several `for loops` to do this and this seems not very nice to me.

Comment: @Robin You don't have to update the association, only the getter. Or is that also a problem?

Comment: Well in the example above, if I would add another Product. Then I would have to update all Products, but I have only the available Products. Now I need to merge both lists.

Comment: @Robin Did you try this? I think it should work fine. If it doesn't work when you add a product, what exactly goes wrong?

Comment: It works, but I think it's not something I would consider a good solution. Therefore, I was looking for a better solution, since I have no idea for a better solution.

Comment: @Robin I agree it is not very charming :) This is probably the best it gets with `Many-To-Many`. You should also realize that adding a new product through a collection like this will always initialize the collection (load all related products from the database). This is another reason why a real `Many-To-Many` is not so common. You could change to one-to-many/many-to-one with three classes ([read details on that also here](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#many-to-many-unidirectional)).

Comment: @Robin I updated my answer with another option. More solutions I don't know.